# How to rotate a label vertically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

NSLineBreakByCharWrapping doesn't even work when I type it in, have I forgotten to import something? I'm new to Swift.

Comment: If you don't want people to downvote your question you need to do your research first before posting a question here.

Comment: I have downvoted. If you can add some code, or otherwise improve this question, I will undownvote. Please do not offer voting advice here!

Comment: hey halfer, how can I edit my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping
```

Edit: Since you are a beginner I'm doing this for you. (PS: Wish someone did this for me). Post the below code in playground and play around with it until you get the desired result.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label       = UILabel()
        label.text      = "Label"
        label.textColor = .white

        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0

        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 13)])
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```